# How does this nested ternary operator work using javascript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am trying to understand what does this nested ternary operator mean using javascript?

below is the code,

```
const columns = !isUser1Readable
    ? allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser1.includes(column.id))
    : !isUser2Readable
    ? allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser2.includes(column.id))
    : allColumns;
```

what i have understood?

seems like if isUser1Readable evaluates to false it filters allcolumns array such that it doesn't contain column from columnIdsUser1

if isUser1Readable is true and isUser2Readable is false then filters allcolumns array such that it doesn't contain column from columnIdsUser2

But when does allColumns is assigned to columns?

Could someone help me understand what this nested ternary operator does above. Thanks.

Comment: `allColumns` is assigned to `columns` only when `isUser1Readable` is true and `isUser2Readable` is also true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when does allColumns is assigned to columns?

In the remaining case, i.e. where both `isUser1Readable` and `isUser2Readable` are true.

The chained ternary expression can be interpreted as an `if ... else if ... else` sequence:

```
let columns;
if (!isUser1Readable) {
    columns = allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser1.includes(column.id));
} else if (!isUser2Readable) {
    columns = allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser2.includes(column.id));
} else {
    columns = allColumns;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator¹ is *greedy*. The expression is clearer with indentation:

```
const columns = !isUser1Readable
    ? allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser1.includes(column.id))
    : !isUser2Readable
        ? allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser2.includes(column.id))
        : allColumns;
```

- If `!isUser1Readable` is `true`, `columns` is assigned the result of `allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser1.includes(column.id))`.
- Otherwise

  - If `!isUser2Readable` is `true`, `columns` is assigned the reuslt of of `allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser2.includes(column.id))`
  - Otherwise, `columns` is assigned `allColumns`.

> but when does allColumns is assigned to columns?

When both `!isUser2Readable` and `!isUser2Readable` are `false`.

---

¹ Although people frequently call it "the ternary operator," it's actually just **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands). It's currently JavaScript's only ternary operator, but that could change. It's name is "the conditional operator."

Answer (score 1):

As the ternary operator is define like this

```
condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse
```

1. ***Condition***: is the condition which is checked
2. ***exprIfTrue***: is the code which is process in case the `Condition` is evaluate to **true**
3. ***exprIfFalse***: is the code which is process in case the `Condition` is evaludate to **false**

The code which you provide can be refactor like this

```
let allColumns = [];
if(!isUser1Readable) {
    allColumns = allColumns.filter(column => {
        return !columnIdsUser1.includes(column.id);
    });
} else if (!isUser2Readable) {
    allColumns = allColumns.filter(column => {
        return !columnIdsUser2.includes(column.id);
    });
}else {
    columns = allColumns;
}
```

You can learn more about [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

I quite like using nested conditional operators in expressions but I find that authoring style does matter to improve readability. (Although YMMV.)

This is how I would have written it:

```js
const columns =
  ( !isUser1Readable ? allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser1.includes(column.id))
  : !isUser2Readable ? allColumns.filter(column => !columnIdsUser2.includes(column.id))
                     : allColumns);
```

Which reads as:

```
const columns =
  (      if !X : do A
  : else if !Y : do B
               : otherwise do C)
```

So `allColumns` is returned if and only if both booleans (*X* & *Y*) are `true` meaning that the first two checks will both evaluate to `false`.